# Why is htop not displaying colors only for my local machine?

Tags: bash, terminal, colors, zsh, htop

**TL;DR:** htop 3.0.4 on macOS 11.0.1 doesn't display colors when running for my local machine, but if ssh'd into a remote system, running htop from there shows colors with no issues.

---

I'm running into a bit of a strange issue with htop 3.0.4 on macOS 11.0.1. Colors in the application itself do not show up at all:

[image: Colors in the application itself do not show up at all]

In htop settings, the "colors" option is set to "default":

[image: "colors" option is set to "default"]

However, exiting htop gives me correctly displayed colors on my usual terminal prompt, and in other applications. Furthermore, if I ssh into a remote system and use htop via the same terminal session, colors show up totally fine:

[image: colors show up totally fine in remote system]

Problem is reproducible in both iTerm 2 and Terminal, and using zsh and bash on this local system only. `$TERM=xterm-256color`.

I ran the `msgcat` color test in iTerm 2, and everything appears to be in order:

[image: msgcat --color-test]

I've tried repouring the htop package via homebrew and have had no differing results. I checked the htop GitHub and don't see any bugs reminiscent of this issue open, so I am asking here first under the assumption that something is wrong on my local machine.

Why is htop not displaying colors only for my local machine?

Comment: Does `HTOPRC= hotp` show colors? Do color options other than `Default` or `Monochromatic` show colors? Does setting `TERM` to some other value help? (run `ls -R /usr/share/terminfo` to choose from). What if you `ssh localhost` first? Please do not respond in comments. [Edit] and add information to the question body.

Comment: Note some people may take "why?" literally. An answer to "why?" may or *may not* easily lead to an answer to "how to fix?". If you want a fix then consider rephrasing the explicit question in the body. "Why is that and how to fix?" seems fine.

Comment: It's probably because htop is using the (rather old) ncurses 5.7 bundled with MacOS, as I mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647635/term-tmux-256color-causes-error-opening-terminal/647639#647639).

Answer (score 10):

In my case `TERM=xterm htop` worked

Comment: It works, thanks!